# Angular: usage of store (Elf) from facade base class

Tags: angular, typescript

what is the best approach to invoke store in facade base class, so there is possibility to incapsulate logic of widely used methods to work with store

let's say we have store (repository)

```
export class SomeRepository {
   private readonly store;

  constructor() {
      this.store = createStore()
 }
}
```

and we have facade which is extended from base facade

```
export abstract class BaseFacade {
   protected store: ReturnType<typeof createStore>

  constructor(protected store: ReturnType<typeof createStore>) {
      this.store = store;
 }

  setEntity(entity: SomeEntity) {
      this.store.update(setEntities(entity))
  }
}
```

and implementation of Concrete Class

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root'})
export class SomeFacade extends BaseFacade {
     constructor(protected store: Store<SomeRepository>) {       <---- here I have issues, do not know how to invoke store
      super(store)
 }
}
```

in component

```
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private readonly facade: SomeFacade) {}

    ngOnInit() {
         const entity = { name: 'Jon', age: 30 };
         this.facade.setEntity(entity);   <----- so here I can use method from abstract class (and not implement it each time when defining Facade class
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is really no right or wrong answer when it comes to design patterns. You just have to pick the one that works for your app.

I typically don't use facades pattern at all.

Here is the flow I use in my Angular Apps:

> Also I use [NGXS](https://ngxs.io/) as my store. I have never used [elf](https://ngneat.github.io/elf/)

`Component` -> subscribes to the state from the `Store` -> And the `Store` uses `services` to do the necessary business logic.

I personally feel facade introduces hidden flow in your application. It can make the code unnecessarily complicated. Angular DI + Provider is all you need.

Comment: appreciate for your comment. facade is used more like adapter between business logic and store, so store is not modified directly. Store (in Elf) include only logic of manipulating store, facade can also include (besides adapters) some business logic, so this pattern in my opinion helps to achieve couple of SOLID principles. Anyway this is defined architecture in my project, so need to have this extra layer, which adds some complexity to abstract functionality